# Create configuration storage programmattically for list_string

Tags: 8, entities, configuration, deployment

On a paragraph type, I have a field I want to migrate to a new field of type "list_string". To do that in the deployment and like our automatic deployment begin by an update of the database follow by importation of configurations, I want to create the new field programmatically before to do the migration in another hook_update.

I'm using the example of this article https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/programmatically-importing-drupal-8-field-configurations which is perfect except I have a problem because my new field is of type list_string. My configuration for field.storage is:

```
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - options
    - paragraphs
id: paragraph.field_types_link
field_name: field_types_link
entity_type: paragraph
type: list_string
settings:
  allowed_values:
    -
      value: anchor
      label: Ancre
    -
      value: internal
      label: Interne
    -
      value: external
      label: Externe
  allowed_values_function: ''
module: options
locked: false
cardinality: 1
translatable: true
indexes: {  }
persist_with_no_fields: false
custom_storage: false
```

When I create my new field based on my configuration file like that:

```
$field_storage_link = \Drupal::service('config.storage.sync')->read('field.storage.paragraph.field_types_link');

\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_storage_config')
  ->create($field_storage_link)
  ->save();
```

I have this error.

> [error]  The configuration property settings.allowed_values.0.label.0 doesn't exist.

If I remove the list of allowed_values, it works and I can add my field to paragraphes bundles but in this case, I'm not able to do my migration properly because the allowed_values of my field are empty and I don't know how to update it programmatically. Someone can explain what's is the problem in my code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finish by find what was the problem. When I read the config file, my allowed value are of format:

```
[
  [
    'value' => 'anchor',
    'label' => 'Anchor'
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'internal',
    'label' => 'Internal'
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'external',
    'label' => 'External'
  ]
]
```

But the FieldStorageConfig wait a format:

```
[
  'anchor' => 'Anchor',
  'internal' => 'Internal',
  'external' => 'External'
]
```

So I add a transformation before to save my new field:

```
$field_storage_link = \Drupal::service('config.storage.sync')->read('field.storage.paragraph.field_types_link');

$allowed_values_link = [];

foreach($field_storage_link['settings']['allowed_values'] as $value) {
  $allowed_values_link[$value['value']] = $value['label'];
}

$field_storage_link['settings']['allowed_values'] = $allowed_values_link;

\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_storage_config')
      ->create($field_storage_link)
      ->save();

$field_type_link = \Drupal::service('config.storage.sync')->read('field.field.paragraph.link_tdm.field_types_link');

\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_config')->create($field_type_link)->save();
```

It works properly.

Answer (score 0):

For others with the same issue, see this important comment by Berdir at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2944144#comment-12481021
saying:

> That's not the correct way to create a config entity from config.
> Here's a snippet based on what I did just today:

```
  $module_handler = \Drupal::moduleHandler();
  $config_storage = new FileStorage($module_handler->getModule('yourmodule')->getPath() . '/config/install');

  foreach (['field.storage.user.field_name', 'field.field.user.user.field_name'] as $config_name) {
    $config_record = $config_storage->read($config_name);

    $entity_type = \Drupal::service('config.manager')->getEntityTypeIdByName($config_name);
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorageInterface $storage */
    $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type);
    $entity = $storage->createFromStorageRecord($config_record);
    $entity->save();
  }
```

> The important part is "$entity =
> $storage->createFromStorageRecord($config_record);", the config
> structure and config entity structure doesn't always match 1:1.

I can confirm this solved the problem for me with the same error.